# IoC not being resolved automatically

Tags: laravel

I'm implementing repositories in my app. In my PresupuestoController (Presupuesto = Estimate in spanish) PresupuestoRepo gets injected in the constructor:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Paciente;
use App\Repositories\PresupuestoRepository;

class PresupuestosController extends Controller
{
    protected $presupuestoRepo;

    public function __construct(PresupuestoRepository $presupuestoRepo )
    {
        $this->presupuestoRepo = $presupuestoRepo;
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create(Paciente $paciente)
    {
        $presupuesto = $this->presupuestoRepo->createNew($paciente);
        dd($presupuesto);
        return view('presupuesto.edit', compact('paciente'));
    }
}
```

So far so god. It works. But now I need to inject a dependency in the PresupestoRepo itself, PacienteRepository (Paciente = Patient in spanish)

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Models\Presupuesto;
use App\Repositories\PacienteRepository;

class PresupuestoRepository extends BaseRepository {

    protected $pacienteRepo;

    public function __constructor(PacienteRepository $pacienteRepo)
    {
       // THIS CONSTRUCTOR IS **NEVER** CALLED !!!

        $this->pacienteRepo = $pacienteRepo;
        dd($pacienteRepo); // here is the problem: pacienteRepo is NULL !!!
    }

    public function getRepo()
    {
        return $this->presupuestoRepo;
    }
}
```

but PaceinteRepository is not automaticly invoqued, getting null instead.

For the sake of completeness , PacienteRepository:

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories;

use App\Models\Paciente;
use App\Models\Odontograma;



class PacienteRepository extends BaseRepository {

    public function __constructor(){}

    /**
     * @return string
     */    
    public function getClassName() 
    {
        return 'App\Models\Paciente';
    }
 }
```

How to get a PacienteRepo injected in PresupuestoRepository's constructor?

Comment: Have you added your repository in AppServiceProviders.php?

Comment: @GauravDave Is it required? PresupuestoRepository is not registered and is working, being injected in PresupuestoController's constructor. What makes the difference? Sorry, i'm new to this and may be i'm missing sth.

Comment: It is preferred, as it binds the interface with its implementation.

Comment: Repository is not a service provider, so it cannot be registered. My doubt is I'm not able to see the difference. PresupuestoRepository doen't need registration to be injected in the controller...

Comment: I tried to bind it, but it still don't works

Comment: Last thing tried: in AppServiceProvider@register, added: ``` $this->app->bind('PacienteRepository', function ($app) {
            return new App\Repositories\PacienteRepository ;
        });```

Comment: Something unespected is happening: The PresupuestoRepository in being injected in the controller, but the cosntructor IS NEVER called! I'm missing sth important here, but i'm not able to find out.

Comment: Shame on me! __constructor instead of __construct. That was the problem,